# Launch VBS MsgBox but continue the script

Tags: batch-file

I have tried multiple different way to make the below possible but cannot find a way to do it. I have a `ROBOCOPY` script that outputs a VBS messagebox depending on the exit code. However, I want the batch script to continue running and exit even after the messagebox appears. As of right now, I have to click `Ok` for the VBS message box to close and then the command line closes.

Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF

::Delete DB File
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\Agentry Client"
DEL "Agentry.db"
CLS

::Copy new DB file from Fil003
2>nul PUSHD "\\sampleserver\123\123" >nul

ROBOCOPY /ZB /IS /IT /R:3 "\\sampleserver\123\123" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SP\AClient" "AClient.db" /log:"C:\Program Files (x86)\SP\AClient\Acleint.txt" /tee

    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 16 GOTO ER16
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO ER1
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO ER0

:ER0
2>nul POPD >nul 
PUSHD "\\sampleserver\123\123\"
Start /b "" cscript "NoCopy.vbs"
TIMEOUT /T 3
POPD
exit

:ER1
2>nul POPD >nul 
PUSHD "\\sampleserver\123\123\"
Start "" cmd /c cscript "Success.vbs"
TIMEOUT /T 3
POPD
exit

:ER16
2>nul POPD >nul 
PUSHD "\\sampleserver\123\123\"
Start /b "" cscript "FatalError.vbs"
TIMEOUT /T 3
POPD
exit
```

Comment: Don't use `CMD /C` when launching `cscript`.  It is not needed.

Comment: @Squashman even with removing that, the command prompt still waits for me to click and close the VBS script before it proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mshta in vbs rather than msgbox

```
Function mshta(ByVal MessageText, ByVal Title, ByVal PauseTimeSeconds)

    Set WScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    ConfigString = "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")." & "Popup(""" & MessageText & """," & PauseTimeSeconds & ",""" & Title & """))"
    WScriptShell.Run ConfigString

End Function
```

'PauseTimeSeconds' will close the message, or you can set it to 0 for it to remain open until user clicks ok.